# Как сделать общую рамку вокруг пересекающихся элементов?

Tags: html, css

Когда несколько контейнеров с рамкой накладываются друг на друга, можно ли оставить рамку только по краю всех, чтобы внутрь она не заходила? (Как бы сделать один регион, наложив их по **OR** друг на друга, который будет иметь рамку)

```css
body{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div{
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;  
}

#div1{
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color:  LightCoral;
}

#div2{
  left: 70px;
  top: 70px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: LightSalmon;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
</div>
<div id='div2'>
</div>
```

Comment: Только почему or а не xor не понял

Comment: В данном случае не важно, т.к. внутреннюю часть не рассматриваем, а вообще по xor из середины вырежется то, что наложилось, потому or логичнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через `filter:drop-shadow(...);`

```css
body{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.b {
filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 0 black) drop-shadow(0 1px 0 black) drop-shadow(1px 0 0 black) drop-shadow(-1px 0 0 black);
}
div{

  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;  
}

#div1{
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color:  LightCoral;
}

#div2{
  left: 70px;
  top: 70px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: LightSalmon;
}
```

```html
<section class="b">
  <div id='div1'>
  </div>
  <div id='div2'>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: пока не понял, как это работает... дома поиграюсь, разберусь. Но визуально то, что надо было, спасибо

Comment: А, понял... это трюк конечно), а более универсально не получится? Например, если рамка со стилем (пунктирная или двойная), уже работать, естественно не будет.

Comment: Двоюную еще можно сделать а вот пунктир нет

Comment: Это тенями не получится... Где-то тут видел через SVG вроде пунктиром делали, но найти не смог